# Feynman Lectures: Trigonometry Error in Rotational Dynamics?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

I'm reading through Vol. 1 Chaper 18, and Feynman says that in the system:

[image]

([See here](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/img/FLP_I/f18-01/f18-01_tc_big.svg) for a higher resolution copy - can't embed SVGs), the length of $PQ$ is equal to $r\Delta\theta$:

> If $OP$ is called $r$, then the length $PQ$ is $r\Delta\theta$, because of the way angles are defined.

I'm probably being stupid, but surely this should be $r*\tan(\Delta\theta)$? Also, the diagram itself appears to depict an impossible figure. If the lengths of $OP$ and $OQ$ are equal, then the angle $OPQ$ cannot be 90 degrees. Like I said I'm probably being stupid, so hopefully someone can show me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @Floris that is correct - didn't realise there was hotlinking protection.

Comment: Don't worry - it happens a lot. Problem solved; deleting comment now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of the arc PQ is $r\Delta\theta$, as Feynman says, but the difference from $\tan\Delta\theta$ or $2\tan (\Delta \theta/2)$ or something else is negligible because $\Delta \theta$ is assumed to be infinitesimal (infinitely small) in the argument, anyway. For that reason, both angles OPQ and OQP should be taken to be 90 degrees.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand the situation now. I hadn't realised he meant for Δθ to be infinitesimal, as I'm used to d being used to denote it as opposed to Δ.

Comment: Yes, that's very right that you're used to that notation. But Feynman's talk is supposed to be directed even to undergraduates who haven't heard of calculus, or at least who haven't internalized it, so he's just "emulating" much of the wisdom of the calculus without the modern notation for derivatives and infinitesimals.